# I can't install Live Server extension on Visual Studio and it doesn't come up on marketplace search inside VS

Tags: html, css, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, liveserver

"Live Server" extension doesn't appear on extension marketplace inside Visual Studio also "HTML Snippets", I tried downloading the extension from web browser and when I try to install it gives an error, here is the log file

```
10/21/2021 10:57:03 PM - Microsoft VSIX Installer
10/21/2021 10:57:03 PM - -------------------------------------------
10/21/2021 10:57:03 PM - vsixinstaller.exe version:
10/21/2021 10:57:03 PM - 16.11.12
10/21/2021 10:57:03 PM - -------------------------------------------
10/21/2021 10:57:03 PM - Command line parameters:
10/21/2021 10:57:03 PM - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\ServiceHub\Services\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Service\VSIXInstaller.exe,C:\Users\user\Desktop\ritwickdey.LiveServer-5.6.1.vsix
10/21/2021 10:57:03 PM - -------------------------------------------
10/21/2021 10:57:03 PM - Microsoft VSIX Installer
10/21/2021 10:57:03 PM - -------------------------------------------
10/21/2021 10:57:04 PM - Initializing Install...
10/21/2021 10:57:04 PM - Extension Details...
10/21/2021 10:57:04 PM -    Identifier         : LiveServer
10/21/2021 10:57:04 PM -    Name               : Live Server
10/21/2021 10:57:04 PM -    Author             : ritwickdey
10/21/2021 10:57:04 PM -    Version            : 5.6.1
10/21/2021 10:57:04 PM -    Description        : Launch a development local Server with live reload feature for static & dynamic pages
10/21/2021 10:57:04 PM -    Locale             : en-US
10/21/2021 10:57:04 PM -    MoreInfoURL        : 
10/21/2021 10:57:04 PM -    InstalledByMSI     : False
10/21/2021 10:57:04 PM -    SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : [0.0,2147483647.2147483647]
10/21/2021 10:57:04 PM - 
10/21/2021 10:57:04 PM -    SignatureState     : Unsigned
10/21/2021 10:57:04 PM -    Supported Products : 
10/21/2021 10:57:04 PM -        Microsoft.VisualStudio.Code
10/21/2021 10:57:04 PM -            Version : 
10/21/2021 10:57:04 PM - 
10/21/2021 10:57:04 PM -    References         : 
10/21/2021 10:57:04 PM - Signature Details...
10/21/2021 10:57:04 PM -    Extension is not signed.
10/21/2021 10:57:04 PM - 
10/21/2021 10:57:04 PM - Searching for applicable products...
10/21/2021 10:57:04 PM - Found installed product - Global Location
10/21/2021 10:57:05 PM - Found installed product - Visual Studio Community 2019
10/21/2021 10:57:05 PM - VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: One or more extensions are for Visual Studio Code. Try installing them in Visual Studio Code.
   at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.GetInstallableDataImpl(IInstallableExtension extension, String extensionPackParentName, Boolean isRepairSupported, IStateData stateData, IEnumerable`1& skuData)
   at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.GetInstallableData(String vsixPath, String extensionPackParentName, Boolean isRepairSupported, IStateData stateData, IEnumerable`1& skuData)
   at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionPackService.IsExtensionPack(IStateData stateData, Boolean isRepairSupported)
   at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionPackService.ExpandExtensionPackToInstall(IStateData stateData, Boolean isRepairSupported)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize(Boolean isRepairSupported)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)
```

Any idea how to solve this issue or if there is an alternative for live server?

Answer (score 1):

Live Server was deprecated recently in fact of the fact there is a built-in VSCode one. As for HTML snippets, it is suggesting the extension hasn't been signed, meaning it isn't verified. This means that you can't install that extension for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

There is easy way to solve.You can install extension with .vsix file(it is downloaded).
Firstly, go to https://open-vsx.org/ and download the extension that you want.After downloading you will get VSIX file.Final step: open visual studio and go to EXTENSIONS.Click option icon(•••) and find and click (install from VSIX) and then choose your downloaded .vsix file. Done.